# How can I get component's method real name?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, payu

`for clarify next part: payU is the Internet payment operator`

I have a serious problem with integration my Angular app with payU payments. I won't store or pass credit card's data (security reasons) so I choose widget.

The first problem is how to place the widget in the code. Documentation says that I should place script in the following way:

```
<script
    src="https://secure.payu.com/front/widget/js/payu-bootstrap.js"
    pay-button="#pay-button"
    merchant-pos-id="145227"
    shop-name="Nazwa sklepu"
    total-amount="9.99"
    currency-code="USD"
    success-callback="test"
    sig="250f5f53e465777b6fefb04f171a21b598ccceb2899fc9f229604ad529c69532">
</script>
```

How you probably know, you can't set script in your code in this way in Angular so I decided use little walkaround:

```
    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.script = document.createElement('script');
        this.script.setAttribute('src', 'https://secure.payu.com/front/widget/js/payu-bootstrap.js');
        this.script.setAttribute('pay-button', '#pay-button');
        this.script.setAttribute('merchant-pos-id', '145227');
        this.script.setAttribute('total-amount', '9.99');
        this.script.setAttribute('currency-code', 'USD');
        this.script.setAttribute('success-callback', 'test');
        this.script.setAttribute('sig', '4752ce2b163684a9c27cc0923ad46068c04da5d34329f5669ce73dcf96394558');
        this.renderer.appendChild(this.el.nativeElement, this.script);
    }
```

I know it's not a perfect solution (if you know better way to do this, please let me know in comment.

But the main problem is pass name of callback function to `success-callback` attribute. I prepared function in my component, like:

```
    test(arg: any) {
        console.log(arg);
    }
```

But I can't get this name. I was trying:

`this.script.setAttribute('success-callback', this.test.name);`

but property name is empty. Is there a simple way to get real name of method (after typescipt translating) in my component?

BTW.

Adding simple js script to index.html and providing its name works, but i need to call service within my function.

I'm using Angular v7.

Comment: you can try to define your test function on window object. `(window as any).test = this.test`

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation:**

Ok, let's start by explaining the script. Since the script is being added in the global namespace, the success callback refers to a global function with the name 'test' in your above code.

So we need a reference to the angular component's 'test' function in the global namespace of your app, so that it can be accessed on success callback.

**In your component:**

```
import {NgZone} from '@angular/core';

constructor(private zone:NgZone){
    window.callbackComponentRef = {
      testFn: (args) => {
        this.zone.run(() => { this.test(args); })
      } 
    };
}

test() {
    //Whatever code you want to run
}
```

**Then use in script addition code**

```
this.script.setAttribute('success-callback', 'callbackComponentRef.testFn');
```